# How to action a php function in an html form on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a contact form at the moment which actions a separate php page. However, the confirmation is just a white page with some plain text on it. How can I put this php code into my contact form page and action it from there so I can make the confirmation on the same page?

The PHP code is as follows:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "dkxclanx@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Movie Night Review Submissions";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

You will now be redirected back to the original page within 10 seconds.

If the page does not load click <a href ="http://movienightreviews.tk/contact_us.html">here</a> to be redirected now.

<?php
header('Refresh: 10; URL=http://movienightreviews.tk/contact_us.html');
}
die();
?>
```

The html page code currently is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="top">
        <h1>Movie Night Reviews</h1>
        <nav id="mainnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="trailers.php">Trailers</a></li>
                <li class = "review"><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                    <ul id = "dropdown1">
                        <li><a href="civil_war.php">Civil War</a></li>
                        <li><a href="furious_7.html">Furious 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="fantastic_four.html">Fantastic Four</a></li>
                        <li><a href="jurassic_world.html">Jurassic World</a></li>
                        <li><a href="agents_of_shield.html">Agents of Shield</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_us.html"id="thispage">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article id="main">
        <h2>Contact Us by E-Mail</h2>
        <p>To contact us by E-Mail please fill out the following form and click Submit.</p>
       <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
    <h2>Contact Us by Post</h2>
    <p>To contact us by Post please send a letter to the following address:</p>
    <p>
    Joe Bloggs<br>
    The Shed<br>
    Moss Side<br>
    Manchester<br> 
    M15 SHED</p>
    </article>
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <h2>Disclaimer</h2>
        <p>For those who haven't realised, this website is just a test website and there is no such company or people tht rementioned inthis website so do not contact us. </p>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 Movie Night Reviews</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the answers guys!! I did as you said removing the action and putting the php in my page. The function is now working however half of my apge wont show for some reason not sure why though. My new code is now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="top">
        <h1>Movie Night Reviews</h1>
        <nav id="mainnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="trailers.php">Trailers</a></li>
                <li class = "review"><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                    <ul id = "dropdown1">
                        <li><a href="civil_war.php">Civil War</a></li>
                        <li><a href="furious_7.html">Furious 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="fantastic_four.html">Fantastic Four</a></li>
                        <li><a href="jurassic_world.html">Jurassic World</a></li>
                        <li><a href="agents_of_shield.html">Agents of Shield</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_us.html"id="thispage">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <article id="main">
        <h2>Contact Us by E-Mail</h2>
        <p>To contact us by E-Mail please fill out the following form and click Submit.</p>
       <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="#">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<h2>Contact Us by Post</h2>
    <p>To contact us by Post please send a letter to the following address:</p>
    <p>
    Joe Bloggs<br>
    The Shed<br>
    Moss Side<br>
    Manchester<br> 
    M15 SHED</p>
    </article>
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <h2>Disclaimer</h2>
        <p>For those who haven't realised, this website is just a test website and there is no such company or people tht rementioned inthis website so do not contact us. </p>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 Movie Night Reviews</p>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "dkxclanx@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Movie Night Review Submissions";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
</html>
```

Comment: remove action from here `<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">` so it will be like `<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="#">` will keep you on samepage after submitting form

Comment: Just copy your PHP code to your form page and remove the form action.

Comment: @Kyle Could you please see the updated question as its brought on another problem now. Cheers

Comment: @Shehary Could you please see the updated question as its brought on another problem now. Cheers

Comment: @AdamBirds put this on top of your PHP code after <?php `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and see whats causing the problem

Comment: @Shehary No errors are showing up with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You content HTML has to be printed conditionally, so you only show the entire page when the user access it the first time:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // prepare to send email...
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?> 

<!-- success message goes here -->

<?
} else {
?>

<!-- full html goes here -->

<?php
}
?>
```

By the way, you can use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` so you don't have to worry about altering the code in case you rename the PHP file:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it kinda works but the bottom half of the html only shows after they submit the form which is a problem, any other ways to do this?

Comment: That's strange, I see no reason for this not to work, make sure you used that code correctly: First, copy the code from my answer, replace `// prepare to send email...` with your code to send mail up until `@mail(`, replace `success message goes here` with "Thanks" (just to see it working), then replace `full html goes here` with the HTML you presented first.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code can remain almost the same, just paste it into your HTML page and insert the success message where you want it in the HTML with a conditional around it (or set a variable instead of inserting the function call in the conditional):

```
if (@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
    //success message
} else {
    //failure message
}
```

Make sure to use a .php extension on the HTML page, and remove the action attribute of the form.

Comment: Could you please see the updated question as its brought on another problem now. Cheers